# Why is the local address the same as the peer one?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpip, netstat

A weird issue occurred while I was troubleshooting with `ss`, the local address is exactly same as the peer one. Same IP address is ok, but how to explain the same port?

[image: linux ss output]

Answer (score 3):

I found out why, it's the [TCP client self connect.](http://sgros.blogspot.com/2013/08/tcp-client-self-connect.html)

> If you run the following snippet of the Bourne shell code:
>
> ```
> while true
> do
>    telnet 127.0.0.1 50000
> done
> ```
>
> You'll constantly receive message `Connection refused`, but at one point the connection will be established and whatever you type, will be echoed back:
>
> ```
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> Connected to 127.0.0.1.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> test1
> test1
> test2
> test2
> ```
>
> Note that you didn't start any server and there is no process listening on port 50000 on localhost, but yet, it connected! Looking at the output of `netstat` command we see that there is really established connection:
>
> ```
> $ netstat -tn | grep 50000
> tcp    0   0 127.0.0.1:50000  127.0.0.1:50000  ESTABLISHED
> ```

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for sharing your discovery!